# Loading tiles of EXTENT in OpenLayers locally (localStorage)?

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple openlayers 3 map **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/73nLukyw/2/)** , the map initialization code looks like so:

```
var styles = [
    'Road',
    'Aerial',
    'AerialWithLabels',
    'collinsBart',
    'ordnanceSurvey'];
var layers = [];
var i, ii;

var coordinate1, coordinate2;
coordinate1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6013, 12.9044]);
coordinate2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6885, 12.9536]);

for (i = 0, ii = styles.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    layers.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        preload: Infinity,
        extent: [coordinate1[0], coordinate1[1], coordinate2[0], coordinate2[1]],
        myattribute: styles[i],
        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            key: 'Ak-dzM4wZjSqTlzveKz5u0d4IQ4bRzVI309GxmkgSVr1ewS6iPSrOvOKhA-CJlm3',
            imagerySet: styles[i]
            // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
            // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
            // maxZoom: 19
        })
    }));
}
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    // Improve user experience by loading tiles while dragging/zooming. Will make
    // zooming choppy on mobile or slow devices.
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([77.6244159, 12.9370699]),
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 13,
        zoom: 13
    })
});

var select = document.getElementById('layer-select');

function onChange() {
    var style = select.value;
    for (var i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
        console.log(layers[i].get('extent'));
    }
}
select.addEventListener('change', onChange);
onChange();
```

Now my map has a special feature if you noticed , I.E. it has an `extent` set , I.E. tiles beyond a certain extent won't load, now what i really want to acomplish is, i want the tiles for this extent to be loaded from locally I.E. when the user visits my website the second time around , the tiles sound load form his `localstorage` , How can this be accomplished ? or can this be accomplished at all , this is a requirement for my project and i have been stuck for some days now on this , can anybody shed some light on this as to how is this possible?